# statusBarFrame.height returns 1024.0 when in Landscape (iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation, statusbar

I have been using the following code to get the height of the status bar:

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height`

This works perfectly in Portrait mode and returns the expected value (20.0), but when the application is in Landscape, I get the unexpected value of 1024.0 !!

Is anybody able to shed any light on this for me?

iOS version 6.1.3

XCode version 4.6.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might need to use the `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width` on Landscape orientation. Same as `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` gives switched values on Landscape orientation

Comment: We need the `height` how does `orientation` matters, since `height` is the same?

Comment: Hi, sorry just saw the comment... not sure what you mean when you say "since height is the same". The orientation matters, because the statusBarFrame uses the frame inside the screen-coordinates. On portrait, the height will give you 20 but on landscape it is the width that gives the value @Ollie is searching for.

Comment: height of status bar is same in both the orientations. Only the width changes.

Comment: Thanks Tamara. It seems that as the active .xib is saved in Portrait, that statusBarFrame will always show the frame as if it were in Portrait too. I just checked the statusBarFrame and returned the width as the height if it returned Landscape. Perfect :)

Comment: Yes, visually the height of the status bar stays the same. But the values of the status bar dimensions are not the same. On landscape w: 20, h: 1024 and on portrait w: 768, h: 20, this is because it is based on the screencoordinates and that is why it depends on the orientation.

Comment: It seems that in iOS 8.0 (not updated to 8.0.2 yet) width/height are **not** switched in Landscape orientation. So status bar height is statusBarFrame.size.height whichever is the orientation. So you have to check iOS version.

Answer (score 13):

Use this if you want to forget about orientation or coordinates related problems:

```
float statusBarHeight = MIN([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height, [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is completely correct. The `statusBarFrame` is in screen coordinates.
You have to use `statusBarOrientation` to check whether you should switch the coordinates.

Comment: This answer is correct, and I used it in conjunction with Tamara Bernad's answer to get what I needed. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

At what point in the app do you get this?
**If it's at first run**, check what orientation your .xib files are in in the project. If they are in portrait then even though the app is started in landscape it hasn't had time to determine orientation and uses the dimensions of the .xib that it's creating the frontmost view controllers view from.

> In iOS 6 the rotation handling and orientation detection changed
>   significantly from iOS 5 and lower, I *beleive* that you can no longer
>   rely on the orientation of the status bar for these values.

[this may help](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check for the orientation, just use the UIView convenient method for converting the frame:

```
CGRect statusBarFrame = [self.view convertRect:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame] fromView:self.view.window];
```

Comment: Accessing the height of the frame returned by this snippet performs the same as other answers here, but it describes whats happening much more clearly. +1

Answer (score -1):

Clean Build your code and check whether `orientationChange` methods are called.
Please specify the iOS version as well

Comment: I have already tried a Clean Build, and the orientationChange methods definitely get called. I've edited the original post to show the iOS version (6.1.3)

Comment: @Ollie: Then try quitting restarting `Xcode` or build with a lower version.

Comment: It wasn't a case of the version of Xcode or needing a clean build. The symptoms were present in my other projects and my colleagues projects too. Try it yourself. Tamara Bernad has the correct solution